# Minimum cost k-node subtree in a graph

Tags: graph, combinatorics

There is an un-directed cyclic graph with n nodes and there is a root node. Each node in the graph has a weight. Given a integer k, select k nodes from the graph with the two below conditions :
•   Sum of weights on the selected nodes should be minimum
•   All the selected nodes should have a path to root node

The weights are on the nodes.

Answer (score 0):

First split the graph into its connected components. Thereafter only consider the component containing the root node. Select the top k vertices under a non-decreasing ordering by weight. Note that neither existence nor uniqueness of a solution is guaranteed.

***Caveat***

Something may be missing from the problem description, as the cyclicity of the graph does not figure in the solution.

Possibly the sum of weights of all vertices of the tree composed of the paths from the solution nodes to the root are to be minimized ? The question heading suggests this but the body says otherwise.

In case this surmise is true, the task to solve is the [node-weighted Steiner Tree](http://theory.cs.uni-bonn.de/info5/steinerkompendium/node15.html) problem restricted to instances with `k` being the size of terminals.

Comment: Hi, I will again formulate the problem statement. There is a cyclic, undirected graph with each vertices having weight. One vertex is considered root vertex throughout the problem. Now, I can select k vertices such that sum of weights on the k vertices should be minimum and each of the k vertices should connect to root. The outcome will be a tree of k vertices having root. Hop I am clear this time.

Comment: In that case my solution holds.

Comment: I could not understand it. Can you explain it with an example ?

Comment: k is the total number of nodes in the tree.